# Draw a triangle with CSS?

Tags: css, drawing

I know you can draw with a canvas element, I just wanted to know if it was possible to draw a triangle next to a link without using a canvas element? I just want a small < 16px down arrow.

Comment: My initial reaction is "no, CSS doesn't draw anything, it only *styles*, use an image background", but then I'm sure somebody would come along with some ingenious hack… :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Nope.**

The closest you could get is by using an ASCII key, `&darr;` to be precise.

It produces an arrow like this ↓

*Of course a background-image will do the trick, but that's quite obvious, innit? :)*

Answer (score 13):

Here is my take on drawing a triangle in css. You can view it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExMMx/). Have not done any browser testing (works in Chrome!)

The CSS is pretty simple:

```
.triangle{
display: block;
border-bottom: 16px solid transparent;
border-left: 16px solid red;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
}
```

If you want it pointing in a different direction, just alter the borders. For example, the following will point the triangle downward:

```
.triangle{
display: block;
border: 16px solid transparent;
border-top: 16px solid red;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
}
```

**Edit:** Works in latest IE, FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

U+25BC: Black Down-Pointing Triangle exists in Unicode. Here it is: ▼

You could use this CSS to apply it:

```
a:before {
    content: "▼";
}
```

It's probably better to use a `background-image` though. That way, you would not depend on the existence of such special characters in the font the web browser uses, and it would show up in IE 6/7.  For example:

```
a {
    background-image: url("arrow.gif");
    padding-left: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No. Just use a special ASCII character, `&#darr;`, no CSS required:

```
<span id = "down-arrow">&#darr;</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my simple drawing for the triangle using CSS:

```
<div style="border: 11px solid transparent; border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);"></div>
```

If you need to change the direction, just replace **border-right-color** with **border-*direction*-color**.
And maybe you use `position: absolute;` and `margin-top` and `margin-left` properties to set the position.